# Type Hinting: Use of Elipsis

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to use Elipsis. Here's the declaration of the method

```py
def func_test(
    self,
    top_k: int,
    tensor_1: torch.Tensor,
    tensor_2: torch.Tensor,
) -> list[list[int], ...]:
```

Pylance, in Visual Studio Code, is giving me the error

```
> "..." not allowed in this context
```

However, mypy [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html#useful-built-in-types) state that it should be possible. The hack I used to solve this was to use the var `Ellipsis`, but I'm not sure whether this is the pythonic way.

Comment: Typo? Did you mean to write `tuple[T, ...]`?

Comment: What do you want `...` to mean in a `list` type hint?

Comment: It's not clear what you think `list[list[int], ...]` would mean. `list[list[int]]` is already the list equivalent of `tuple[list[int], ...]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read into the documentation something it doesn't say. It *only* shows `tuple`, not any other generic type, using `...`.

`list` takes exactly one argument: the element type.

`dict` takes exactly two arguments: the key type and the value type.

`tuple` can take an arbitrary number of elements, one type per "dimension". A special case for the two-argument form is to supply `...` for the second argument, which indicates a homogeneous tuple of arbitrary size, the type of each element specified by the first argument.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, ellipsis also has special meaning in the generic type [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) (as the first type argument) to leave the parameter types of the callable unspecified, and in the special typing construct [`Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate) (as the last argument, less commonly used).